# Custom cell in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am making a custom cell which has text fields and as a result the custom cell is greater than the size of the iphone screen.But i am not being able to do horizontal scroll to reach the end of the cell.
I have tried using viewController and adding table view to it as well as creating table view controller and adding custom cell to it.

when doing it through TableViewController,I am not able to horizontally scroll it,whereas i am not getting how to add Custom cell class to the tableView object placed in viewController.I know that UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView but not able to implement it.Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per the documentation [at](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> A table view in the UIKit framework is limited to a single column
>   because it is designed for a device with a small screen. UITableView
>   is a subclass of UIScrollView, which allows users to scroll through
>   the table, **although UITableView allows vertical scrolling only.**

so as desired in your case you will have to take some other approach.  Now using Custom cell with TextFields should not actually need you to require Horizonatl scrolling. If the text is really large you would like to consider using TextView instead of TextFields.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should be truncating your text. But if it is important for you to display the entire text, add a scroll view as a subview (or set it as the content view) and add your labels to the subview. Each cell will then be individually horizontally scrollable.